# Name (and set) variables in current shell, based on line input data

Tags: shell, unix

I have a SQL*Plus output written into a text file in the following format:

```
3459906|     |2|X1|WAS1| Output1
 334596|     |2|X1|WAS2| Output1
3495792|     |1|X1|WAS1| Output1
 687954|     |1|X1|WAS2| Output1
```

I need a shell script to fetch the counts which were at the beginning based on the text after the counts.

For example, If the Text is like `|2|X1|WAS1|` , then `3459906` should be passed on to a variable `x1was12` and if the text is like `|2|X1|WAS2|` , then 334596 should be passed on to a variable `x1was22`.

I tried writing a `for` loop and `if` condition to pass on the counts, but was unsuccessful:

```
export filename1='file1.dat'
while read -r line ; do
    if [[ grep -i "*|2|X1|WAS1| Output1*" | wc -l -eq 0 ]] ; then
        export xwas12=sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | \
        sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'
    elif [[ grep -i "*|2|X1|WAS2| Output1*" | wc -l -eq 0 ]] ; then
       export x1was22=sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | \
       sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//' 
    elif [[ grep -i "*|1|X1|WAS1| Output1*" | wc -l -eq 0 ]] ; then
       export x1was11=sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | \
       sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'
    elif [[ grep -i "*|1|X1|WAS2| Output1*" | wc -l -eq 0 ]] 
       export x1was21=sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | \
       sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'
    fi
done < "$filename1"
echo '$x1was12' > output.txt
echo '$x1was22' >> output.txt
echo '$x1was11' >> output.txt
echo '$x1was21' >> output.txt
```

What I was trying to do was:

1. Go to the first line in the file

   - -> Search for the text and if found then assign the `sed` output to the variable
2. Then go to the second line of the file

   - -> Search for the texts in the *if* commands and assign the `sed` output to another variable.
3. same goes for other

Comment: Please show the unsuccessful code, and describe approximately how big the output file is, and how the variables `X` and `Y` are to be used.

Comment: @agc , Here goes the unsuccessful code

Comment: export filename1='file1.dat' while read -r line do if [[ `grep -i "*|2|X1|WAS1| Output1*" | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] then export xwas12=`sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'` elif [[ `grep -i "*|2|X1|WAS2| Output1*" | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] then

Comment: export x1was22=`sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'` elif [[ `grep -i "*|1|X1|WAS1| Output1*" | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] then export x1was11=`sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'` elif [[ `grep -i "*|1|X1|WAS2| Output1*" | wc -l` -eq 0 ]] export x1was21=`sed -n ${line}p $filename1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sed 's/..$//'` fi done < "$filename1"  echo '$x1was12' > output.txt echo '$x1was22' >> output.txt echo '$x1was11' >> output.txt echo '$x1was21' >> output.txt

Comment: What I was trying to do was,Go to the first line in the file -> Search for the text and if found then assign the sed output to the variable Then go to the second line of the file -> Search for the texts in the if commands and assign the sed output to another variable.same goes for other.Newbie to Unix, Let me know where did I go wrong and If there is any different approach to easy this.

Comment: [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) ("How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?") is very topical, and the section on [assigning indirect/reference variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables) covers practices with less potential security impact than using `eval`.

Comment: That said, do you **really** need to assign this to actual shell variables? Could you have an associative array called, say, `vars` and refer to `vars[x1was12]` or `vars[x1was21]` to perform lookups?

Answer (score 1):

If not for the variable names, the whole thing could be done with two commands:

```
cut -d '|' -f1 file1.dat | tr -d ' ' > output.txt
```

The variable names make it more interesting.  Two `bash` methods follow, plus a *POSIX* method...

1. The following `bash` code ought to do what the OP's sample code was
   meant to do:

   ```
   declare $(while IFS='|' read a b c d e f ; do 
                 echo $a 1>&2 ; echo x1${e,,}$c=${a/ /}
             done < file1.dat 2> output.txt )
   ```

   Notes:

   - The `bash` shell is needed for `${e,,}`, (turns "*WAS*" into "*was*"), and `$a/ /}` , (removes a leading space that might be in
     `$a`), and `declare`.
   - The `while` loop parses `file1.dat` and outputs a bunch of variable assignments.  Without the `declare` this code:

     ```
     while IFS='|' read a b c d e f ; do 
          echo x1${e,,}$c=${a/ /} ; 
     done < file1.dat
     ```

     Outputs:

     ```
     x1was12=3459906
     x1was22=334596
     x1was11=3495792
     x1was21=687954
     ```
   - The `while` loop outputs to two separate streams: *stdout* (for the `declare`), and *stderr* (using the `1>&2` and `2>` redirects for
     `output.txt`).
2. Using `bash` associative arrays:

   ```
   declare -A x1was="( $(while IFS='|' read a b c d e f ; do
                            echo $a 1>&2 ; echo [${e/WAS/}$c]=${a/ /}
                         done < file1.dat  2> output.txt  ) )"
   ```

   In which case the variable names require brackets:

   ```
   echo ${x1was[21]}
   687954
   ```
3. *POSIX shell* code (tested using `dash`):

   ```
   eval $(while IFS='|' read a b c d e f ; do 
             echo $a 1>&2; echo x1$(echo $e | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')$c=$(echo $a)
          done < file1.dat 2> output.txt )
   ```

   - `eval` should *not* be used **if** there's any doubt about what's in `file1.dat`. The above code assumes the data in `file1.dat` is
     uniformly dependable.

Comment: I'd be tempted to bold **not** in *"eval should not be used"*. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS='|' read -r count _ n x was _; do
  # remove spaces from all variables
  count=${count// /}; n=${n// /}; x=${x// /}; was=${was// /}
  varname="${x}${was}${n}"
  printf -v "${varname,,}" %s "$count"
done <<'EOF'
3459906|     |2|X1|WAS1| Output1
 334596|     |2|X1|WAS2| Output1
3495792|     |1|X1|WAS1| Output1
 687954|     |1|X1|WAS2| Output1
EOF
```

With the above executed:

```
$ echo "$x1was12"
3459906
```

Of course, the redirection from a heredoc could be replaced with a redirection from a file as well.

---

How does this work? Let's break it down:

- Every time `IFS='|' read -r count _ n x was _` is run, it reads a single line, separating it by `|`s, putting the first column into `count`, discarding the second by assigning it to `_`, reading the third into `n`, the fourth into `x`, the fifth into `was`, and the sixth and all following content into `_`. This practice is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- `count=${count// /}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which prunes spaces from the variable `count`, by replacing all such spaces with empty strings. See also [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).
- `"${varname,,}"` is another parameter expansion, this one converting a variable's contents to all-lowercase. (This requires bash 4.0; in prior versions, consider `"$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$varname")` as a less-efficient alternative).
- `printf -v "$varname" %s "value"` is a mechanism for doing an [indirect assignment](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables) to the variable named in the variable `varname`.

Comment: I have got a new challenge here... let us consider that input like 
`3459906|     |1|X1|WAS1| Output1
 334596|     |2|X1|WAS2| Output1
3495792|     |1|X1|WAS1| Output1`
that means i will get two variables like x1was11 with the count 3459906 and for the third I will get the same variable x1was11 with count 3495792 ... Can I add any condition that if there are two variables with same name and different counts, they will be summed up like in this case x1was11 should be 3459906+3495792 = 6955698